# Passing sensitive data between two ASP.NET pages

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have some sensitive data which I need to pass on from one page to another who also happen to be on two different subdomains of the same domain. If possible, can this be achieved completely at the client side? Passing in URLs or cookies is not an option since this would expose the data.

Answer (score 1):

If it is sensitive information, you shouldn't be relying on the client. Using a [backchannel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-channel#In_IT_Security) between the servers would be best.

If you must, you will need to establish a secure connection - something like an HTML post over SSL would do.

This would still be susceptible to [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your security requirements, you can emit a `<form>` which POSTs the data to the second server.
Make sure that both connections use SSL.

You could also send an HTTPS request directly from the first page to the second on the server (using HttpWebRequest)

Answer (score 0):

If it really is sensitive, you should get an SSL certificate to encrypt the traffic. Then you would be able to use cookies or POSTs without worrying that they will be intercepted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just encrypt the data, pass and decrypt the other end?

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending how sensitive the data is, you could always pass as encrypted query arguments (see http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/security/encrypting-query-arguments).

Another approach using ASP.NET is to postback to the target URL (see http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-implement-a-cross-page-postback-in-aspnet). Why not simply pass the data this way to the target page in the first place?